# Solve equations of combing min and max functions

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

How to solve an equations if it looks like as follows:
$min\left\{d_1, max\{c_1,a_1*x+b_1\}\right\} + min\left\{d_2, max\{c_2,a_2*x+b_2\}\right\} + min\left\{d_3, max\{c_3,a_3*x+b_3\}\right\} = e$

Comment: Have you tried applying the bisection algorithm and isolating short interval containing a root?

Comment: @CarlChristian yes, but there is many min function in my problem. Sometimes  there is ten-thousand min functions, i tried the bisection algorithm in my case. if i use very short interval, bisection algorithm is too slow.

Comment: Yes, but on each sufficiently small interval all your terms reduce to a polynomial of degree at most 1. At that point an exact solve is possible.

Comment: Is there any other information which you can provide? Have you vectorized your function evaluations? How have you implemented the maximum/minimum function: slow conditional jumps or fast arithmetic? What sort of computational speed are you looking for? Your functions reminds me of the height of a landscape for a computer game. Can you not approximate it with a spline and obtain an approximation root using, say, the secant method. There are other possibilities, but what is really needed is additional information from you.

Comment: @CarlChristian thank you very much. i have implemented the function and solved my problem, based on this discussion (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145458/solve-equations-using-the-max-function). Misha Lavrov provided a same solution to my problem.

Comment: the bisection algorithm is a general solution to these problems. my problem is from online advertisement allocation, the e is one advertisement demand,  each min function is a supply for this demand. so in online advertisement allocation, the amount of supply may be billions for each e.

Comment: Thank you for providing the background information. I collect examples, would you happen to have a reference?

Comment: yes, u want the problem reference or the solution reference?  the problem is similar to this paper from yahoo lab (SHALE: An Efficient Algorithm for Allocation of Guaranteed Display Advertising)

Answer (score 1):

Each term $\min\{d_i, \max\{c_i, a_i x + b_i\}\}$ has two "corner points" $\frac{c_i-b_i}{a_i}$ and $\frac{d_i - b_i}{a_i}$ where its behavior changes. A reasonable first step is to sort all the corner points from least to greatest, remembering the term they came from.

This takes $O(n \log n)$ time for a function with $n$ terms, but after doing so, searching for a place where the function equals $e$ can be done in $O(n)$ time. This is pretty good, considering that evaluating the function at a single point takes $O(n)$ time all on its own! And if you have to solve the equation for many different values of $e$, the sorting only has to be done once.

Start by evaluating the function at a value of $x$ smaller than the first corner point. Here, each term is equal to either $c_i$ or $d_i$, depending on the sign of the slope $a_i$.

From here, iterate through the corner points from least to greatest, keeping track of two things:

1. The current function value (which starts at the value you've chosen);
2. The current slope (which starts at $0$).

When you reach a corner point, you can update the function value (using the previous function value and the current slope) and the slope (which changes by $\pm a_i$ when we reach a corner of the $i^{\text{th}}$ term).

If the previous function value was smaller than $e$, and the new function value is bigger than $e$, or vice versa, then we can interpolate between the current corner point and the previous corner point to find the place where the function value is equal to $e$. (Between two corners, the function is linear, with a slope we know.)

If we're going to be solving equations for the same function multiple times, we might as well save the function values at each corner point, after we've computed them once. Once we've done that, a bisection search will solve the equation in only $O(\log n)$ time. (To help the bisection search along, we should remember the location of the minimum and maximum value we've computed.)

Comment: thank you very much, i just used the similar solution to the sub-probelm in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145458/solve-equations-using-the-max-function. Based on the above solution, i have extended it to my problem and solved it.